# How do I check if a record already exists in my db when posting with Ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, database

How do I check if a record already exists in my db when posting with Ajax?

Here is my Ajax code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "team_selections#create",
        data: {
            team_selection: {
                season_id: "1",
                club_id: "1",
                player_id: id,
                fixture_week: "1",
                position: pos
            }
        },
        dataType: "html"
    })
```

Here is my Rails controller code:

```
    def create
        if !TeamSelection.where(season_id: params[:season_id], club_id: params[:club_id], player_id: params[:player_id], fixture_week: params[:fixture_week], position: params[:position]).exists?
        TeamSelection.create(selection_params)
        end
    end


private
  def selection_params
    params.require(:team_selection).permit(:season_id, :club_id, :player_id, :fixture_week, :position)
  end
```

Comment: Please specify which exact method/line is not working ? Does the query in the `if` condition return the proper record if its present ?

Comment: The controller should return some response saying record already exists. Currently, it's not returning anything.

Comment: First, add a validation in model if you don't want similar records to be created more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use find_or_create_by rails method in your controller. this will finds the first record with the given attributes, or creates a record with the attributes if one is not found.This method always returns a record, but if creation was attempted and failed due to validation errors it won’t be persisted, you get what create returns in such situation.

```
def create
  TeamSelection.find_or_create_by(selection_params)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Jagdeep commented correctly: add a validation in the model if you don't want similar records to be created more than once.
But here controller is not returning any response like 'Record already exists'
Replace your `create` method with

```
def create
    is_record_present = TeamSelection.where(season_id: params[:season_id], club_id: params[:club_id], player_id: params[:player_id], fixture_week: params[:fixture_week], position: params[:position]).exists?
  if !is_record_present
    TeamSelection.create(selection_params)
  else
    #return respose for example
    render json: {message: 'Record already present'}, status: :bad_request
  end
end
```

Comment: Can I ask why adding it to a variable is any different to typing it outright as I did previously?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check with the help of a `before_action`.

```
before_action :check_record_exists?

def create
  TeamSelection.create(selection_params)
  render_something
end

private

def check_record_exists?
  if TeamSelection.where(selection_params.slice(:season_id, :club_id, :player_id, :fixture_week, :position)).exists?
    render json: { error: 'Record already exists' }
  end
end

def selection_params
  params.require(:team_selection).permit(:season_id, :club_id, :player_id, :fixture_week, :position)
end
```

**NOTE:** You definitely need to have a validation on model to prevent creation of such records. Don't just rely on checks in controller or the JS.